# Kivy: How can I apply the ScrollView I created in my KV file with the Accordion i made in my Python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I've created Accordion in Python due to the amount of AccordionItems depend on the amount of lines from the text file and I've created the scrollview in my KV file. How do I apply the scrollview to the Accordion so I can scroll down the Accordion  and not the button I made in KV?

Do I have to make all my code Python side for it to work, or am I able to make some of it in Python and KV and somehow hook the both together?

*.py

```
#imported from kivy framework
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty,ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.image import Image
import dictionaryData
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
import os
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion, AccordionItem
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.app import runTouchApp



class Main_Screen(Screen):

    random_number = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main_Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        pass

class Dictionary_Screen(Screen):
    layout = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')    #instantiate BoxLayout
        self.add_widget(layout)    #add BoxLayout to screen

        file1 = open('dict.txt','r')

        accordion = Accordion(orientation='vertical')    # instantiate Accordion
        layout.add_widget(accordion)    # add Accordion to BoxLayout

        for lines in file1:
            fields = lines.split(',')
            #   Tuple unpacking
            Data = (fields[0], fields[1])
            Title,Description = Data
            print(Title,Description)
            item = AccordionItem(title=Title)
            item.add_widget(Label(text=Description, color=(0,0,0,1)))
            accordion.add_widget(item)    # add AccordionItem to Accordion

#class for all screens
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
   pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
       # declaring time from python, and making it refresh every second
        self.now = datetime.now()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_clock, 1)

    def update_clock(self, *args):
        self.now = self.now + timedelta(seconds=1)
        self.root.get_screen("Main_Screen").ids["CurrentTime"].text = self.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

MainApp().run()
```

*.KV

```
#:kivy 1.0
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#styles that will apply to all intences for each tag
<MDRaisedButton>:
    font_size:18
#declaring screen managers and printing them in this order
ScreenManagement:
    Main_Screen:
        name: "Main_Screen"
    Dictionary_Screen:
        name: "Dictionary_Screen"
<Main_Screen>:
    FloatLayout:
        spacing: 10
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: hex('#eff3fa')
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        #Navbar
        MDToolbar:
            id: fb
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top':1.0}
            size_hint_y:None
            height: 50
            title: "Virtual Assistant"
            md_bg_color: hex('#132843')
            Label:
                id: CurrentTime
                font_size:18
                size_hint_x: .1
                color: (1,1,1,1)
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: 10
            padding: 50
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: hex('#000')
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
            Button:
                text: "Dictionary"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "Dictionary_Screen"
            Label:
                id: label1
                text: root.random_number
                color:(1,0,1,1)
<Dictionary_Screen>:
    name: "Dictionary_Screen"
    view: view
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: 1, .1
        # setting the width of the scrollbar to 50pixels
        bar_width: 50
        # setting the color of the active bar using rgba
        bar_color: 5, 10, 15, .8
        # setting the color of the inactive bar using rgba
        bar_inactive_color: 5, 20, 10, .5
        # setting the content only to scroll via bar, not content
        scroll_type: ['bars']
        GridLayout:
            id:view
            size_hint_y: None
            cols: 1
            minimum_height: self.height
            Button:
                text:"back"
                on_release: app.root.current = "Main_Screen"
```

*.txt

```
CPU,CPU_INFORMATION
RAM,RAM_INFORMATION
SOMETHING,SOMETHING_INFORMATION
SOMETHING,SOMETHING_INFORMATION
SOMETHING,SOMETHING_INFORMATION
SOMETHING,SOMETHING_INFORMATION
SOMETHING,SOMETHING_INFORMATION
SOMETHING,SOMETHING_INFORMATION
SOMETHING,SOMETHING_INFORMATION
SOMETHING,SOMETHING_INFORMATION
SOMETHING,SOMETHING_INFORMATION
SOMETHING,SOMETHING_INFORMATION
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `ScrollView`, you must allow its child to be larger than the `ScrollView` itself. Here is my modified version of your code with some changes:

```
#imported from kivy framework
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import StringProperty,ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion, AccordionItem



class Main_Screen(Screen):

    random_number = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main_Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        pass

class Dictionary_Screen(Screen):
    layout = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.accordion = None


    def on_enter(self, *args):

        file1 = open('dict.txt','r')

        if self.accordion is None:
            self.accordion = Accordion(orientation='vertical', size_hint=(1,None), height=150)    # instantiate Accordion
            self.ids.view.add_widget(self.accordion)  # add Accordion to GridLayout
        else:
            self.accordion.clear_widgets()  # clear out all the AccordionItems
            self.accordion.height = 150  # set a starting height (to account for the expanded height of an item)

        item_height = 40  # height to use for each AccordionItem
        for lines in file1:
            fields = lines.split(',')
            #   Tuple unpacking
            Data = (fields[0], fields[1])
            Title,Description = Data
            print(Title,Description)
            item = AccordionItem(title=Title)
            item.add_widget(Label(text=Description, color=(0,0,0,1), size_hint=(1, None), height=item_height))
            self.accordion.height += item_height  # increase Accordion height for his item
            self.accordion.add_widget(item)    # add AccordionItem to Accordion

#class for all screens
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
   pass

kv = '''
#:kivy 1.0
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#styles that will apply to all intences for each tag
<MDRaisedButton>:
    font_size:18
#declaring screen managers and printing them in this order
ScreenManagement:
    Main_Screen:
        name: "Main_Screen"
    Dictionary_Screen:
        name: "Dictionary_Screen"
<Main_Screen>:
    FloatLayout:
        spacing: 10
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: hex('#eff3fa')
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        #Navbar
        MDToolbar:
            id: fb
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top':1.0}
            size_hint_y:None
            height: 50
            title: "Virtual Assistant"
            md_bg_color: hex('#132843')
            Label:
                id: CurrentTime
                font_size:18
                size_hint_x: .1
                color: (1,1,1,1)
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: 10
            padding: 50
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: hex('#000')
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
            Button:
                text: "Dictionary"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "Dictionary_Screen"
            Label:
                id: label1
                text: root.random_number
                color:(1,0,1,1)
<Dictionary_Screen>:
    name: "Dictionary_Screen"
    view: view
    ScrollView:
        # size_hint: 1, 1  # this is the default
        # setting the width of the scrollbar to 50pixels
        bar_width: 50
        # bar_margin: 20
        # setting the color of the active bar using rgba
        bar_color: 5, 10, 15, .8
        # setting the color of the inactive bar using rgba
        bar_inactive_color: 5, 20, 10, .5
        # setting the content only to scroll via bar, not content
        scroll_type: ['bars']
        GridLayout:
            id:view
            size_hint_y: None
            cols: 1
            # minimum_height: self.height
            height: self.minimum_height
            Button:
                text:"back"
                on_release: app.root.current = "Main_Screen"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1] + 10


'''
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
       # declaring time from python, and making it refresh every second
        self.now = datetime.now()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_clock, 1)
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def update_clock(self, *args):
        self.now = self.now + timedelta(seconds=1)
        self.root.get_screen("Main_Screen").ids["CurrentTime"].text = self.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

MainApp().run()
```

I have added the 'kv' file as a string, just for my own convenience.
In your 'kv', under the `GridLayout`, you have:

```
minimum_height: self.height
```

but that is a bit backwards, it should be:

```
height: self.minimum_height
```

That tells the `GridLayout` to adjust its height to the minimum that will contain all its children.

I have moved the code that creates the `Accordion` into an `on_enter` method so that the `id` for the `GridLayout` is available (it is not ready inside the `__init__` method).

I have also eliminated the `BoxLayout` as unnecessary, and set the `size_hint` of the `Accordion` to `(1, one)` to allow me to set the `height` of the `Accordion`. Then I calculate a `height` for the `Accordion` based on the number of `AccordionItems` that get added to it.

Comment: Once again you have saved me. Before I even asked this question I spent hours reading the documentation, but they don't clearly explain it like you do. How did you go about learning from Kiv?

Comment: What is the reason behind the if statement if you don't mind me asking? Code still works fine without it.

Comment: The `if`  in the `on_enter` method is to avoid adding all the `AccordionItems` multiple times. Without it, your code would double the length of the `Accordion` every time you open that `Screen`.